# WPF RichTextBox lock paragraph font

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm trying to figure out how the documents in RichTextBox work.
What I want to achieve is to change selected text font but, not replace a specific one.
So whenever I select text and press a button to replace the font it should keep that one I want but replace all others.

Comment: Can you show what you want to achieve with an example? Changing a font of a selected text is very simple operation. It's necessary to determine the `TextRange` of the text and then to use the `ApplyPropertyValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty)` to evaluate currently applied font and then apply `.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, "your-font-here")` if all necessary conditions are satisfied.